# NoMethodError in EventsController#create: undefined method `event_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm trying to set up a way to create new events in my Rails app. However, when I go to the correct page (according to my routes) in order to make a new event, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in EventsController#create 
undefined method `event_url for #<EventsController:0x000000035a9dc8>
```

This is the relevant area (line 23):

```
  21 respond_to do |format|
  22 if @event.save
  23 format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
  24 format.json { render :show, event: :created, location: @event }
  else
  25 format.html { render :new }
```

This is what my server log says when I try to load the page:

```
Started GET "/create_event" for 12.43.117.2 at 2015-04-17 15:59:57 +0000
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
(16.5ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "events" DEFAULT VALUES
(27.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 503ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `event_url' for #   <EventsController:0x00000004aebd80>):
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:21:in `create'


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-  4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.7ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (10.7ms)
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (155.6ms)
```

Github repo: http://github.com/yamilethmedina/wheels_registration

I have Ruby on Rails 4, devise, and simple_form installed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `redirect_to` with an object in Rails, it will attempt to redirect you to the appropriate `show` action for that object. In this case, with an `event` it would try a route for `EventsController#show`.

In your `routes.rb` file, you have not defined a route for the `show` action in `EventsController` – by adding that, you will be able to get the redirect that you want.

Also, since you already have the other actions like `create` and `index` defined, you can replace them all with `resources :events` in your `routes.rb` file as that will generate all of them automatically.

Comment: And don't forget about plural form: resources :events

Comment: @samsymons @beargrylls When I replaced all of the actions with `resources :events`, I got a `NameError in Profiles#show` in `application.html.erb` that says `undefined local variable or method `event_path'` when linking to All Events in the nav bar: `<b><a href="#" class="brand">WHEELS Registration</a></b>
         <ul class ="nav">
           <%= link_to "All Statuses", feed_path %> |
           <%= link_to "All Events", event_index %>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav pull-right">
           <% if user_signed_in? %>`

Comment: Use `events_path` instead of _event_

Comment: @BearGrylls thanks! that solved that problem, but I now I get a 404 error and the server log says: `Started GET "/create_event" for 12.43.117.2 at 2015-04-17 16:44:02 +0000
Processing by ProfilesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"profile_name"=>"create_event"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."profile_name" = 'create_event'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered public/404.html within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 148ms (Views: 145.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)` How do I get it to use EventsController instead? rake db:migrate?

Comment: Try to use path `/new` for creating new events. Action `create` is used to create a new entry in the collection, in your db

Comment: @BearGrylls I'm still having the same issue; I get a 404 and it says that new_event (which is in my routes) is being processed by the ProfilesController instead of the EventsController.

Comment: 1. Remove any strings from your `routes.rb` that contains word `event`. 2. Leave only `resources :events`. 3. Take a look at `rake routes` and see what variables(prefixes) and URI patterns it produces. 4. Use prefixes for creating links urls like `new_event_path` or `events_path`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to redirect to the 'show' action

```
23 format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
```

But there is no route to action 'show' in your config/routes.rb

Comment: When I do `rake routes`, I have this though: `events_show GET    /events/show(.:format)           events#show` How is that different from a route to action 'show'?

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue: `` NoMethodError (undefined method `event_url' for #   <EventsController:0x00000004aebd80>) ``

Are you trying to pass in an event_url? Your events table doesn't have an event_url. So the fix would be a few things:

1. `rails g migration AddEventUrlToEvents event_url:string`
2. `rake db:migrate`
3. Add `event_url` to your permitted params in your events controller.